# Looping an animation

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I've created a working animation method for a simple `Canvas` [library](https://github.com/khanfusiion3/CanvasJS/blob/master/canvas.js) I'm creating, but I can't quite figure out how to make the animation loop -- from the method itself, given an option. What I mean by that is I know how to loop it in the application itself but not just if I, say, pass the method a `loop` parameter and then it does it for me. Here's the animation snippet:

```
Canvas.objects.Base.prototype.animate = function (options) {
    options.easing = Canvas.animation.easing[options.easing] || options.easing;
    options.duration = Canvas.animation.durations[options.duration] || options.duration * 1000;
    var start = Date.now(),
      total = start + options.duration,
      old = {},
      id,
      self = this;
    for (var i in options.properties) {
      if (options.properties.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        old[i] = this[i];
      }
    }
    (function update() {
      var now = Date.now(),
        progress = Math.min((options.duration - (total - now)) / options.duration, 1);
      for (var i in options.properties) {
        if (options.properties.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
          self[i] = options.easing(now - start, old[i], options.properties[i] - old[i], options.duration);
        }
      }
      if (progress < 1) {
        id = requestAnimationFrame(update);
      } else {
        id = cancelAnimationFrame(id);
        if (options.loop) {
          var animate = function () {
            for (var j in options.properties) {
              self[j] = old[j];
            }
            if (!options.callback) {
              self.animate({
                properties: options.properties,
                easing: options.easing,
                duration: options.duration,
                callback: animate
              });
            } else {
              self.animate({
                properties: options.properties,
                easing: options.easing,
                duration: options.duration,
                callback: function() {
                  options.callback();
                  animate();
                }
              });
            }
          };
          options.callback = animate;
        }
        if (options.callback) {
          options.callback();
        }
      }
    }());
  };
```

Now, here's the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/khanfused/ndg4yLrd/12/) I had to make the loop work outside of the method itself:

```
var animate = function () {
  circle.x = test.canvas.width / 2;
  circle.y = test.canvas.height / 2;
  circle.animate({
    properties: {
        x: test.canvas.width
    },
    easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
    duration: 1,
    callback: function () {
        circle.animate({
        properties: {
            y: test.canvas.height
        },
        easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
        duration: 1,
        callback: animate
      });
    }
  });
};

// 'animate` is called later on a click
```

With the code I have in the method now, once it performs the initial animation, it does revert to all of it's properties before the animation, but then sits there until the window is clicked again.

EDIT: Oh, and here's the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/khanfused/ndg4yLrd/10/) I have now that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. After a bit of debugging I realized the problem was options.duration. Not sure exactly what it was, but it was not functioning properly. Basically I replaced options[foo] with a static value and tried that for each one and the only time it failed was if I used options.duration and not a static value. Problem was the duration was being multiplied by 1000 every time making it run way too slowly to see anything. Again, I don't exactly know why, but the point is... I fixed it. [Code](https://jsfiddle.net/khanfused/ndg4yLrd/14/). All I had to do to fix the overly high duration was remove `* 1000` and sanitize my other values in the code.

```
Canvas.objects.Base.prototype.animate = function(options) {
  options.easing = Canvas.animation.easing[options.easing] || options.easing;
  options.duration = Canvas.animation.durations[options.duration] || options.duration;
  var start = Date.now(),
    total = start + options.duration,
    old = {},
    id,
    self = this;
  for (var i in options.properties) {
    if (options.properties.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      old[i] = this[i];
    }
  }
  if (options.loop) {
    var animate = function() {
      for (var j in options.properties) {
        self[j] = old[j];
      }
      console.log(options.duration);
      self.animate({
        properties: options.properties,
        easing: options.easing,
        duration: options.duration,
        callback: animate
      });
    };
    options.callback = animate;
  }
  (function update() {
    var now = Date.now(),
      progress = Math.min((options.duration - (total - now)) / options.duration, 1);
    for (var i in options.properties) {
      if (options.properties.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        self[i] = options.easing(now - start, old[i], options.properties[i] - old[i], options.duration);
      }
    }
    if (progress < 1) {
      id = requestAnimationFrame(update);
    } else {
      id = cancelAnimationFrame(id);
      if (options.callback) {
        options.callback();
      }
    }
  }());
};
```